This question is for Jehovah's Witnesses. Who is the singular Lord of lords in heaven according to Deuteronomy 10:17?
Deuteronomy 10:17, "For the Lord your God is the God of gods and the Lord of lords, the great the mighty, and the awesome God who does not show partiality, nor take a bribe."
Please reconcile Deuteronomy 10:17 with Revelation 17:14, "These will rage war against the Lamb, and the Lamb will overcome them, BECAUSE He is Lord of lords and King of kings, and those who are with Him are the called and chosen and faithful." Who is the singular Lord of lords in heaven in this verse? Is it possible that the "SINGULAR" Lord of lords encapsulates both of them?

Mr. Bond, which Bible translation do you quote re Deuteronomy 10:17? I ask because my NWT says "For Jehovah your God is the God of gods and the Lord of lords." My NWT translation for Revelation 17:14 says "These will battle with the Lamb, but, because he is Lord of lords and King of kings, the Lamb will conquer them."

I use the NASB. My NWT of Deut. 10:17 reads,  "For Jehovah YOUR God, is the God of gods and the Lord of lords, the God great, mighty and fear-inspiring, who treats none with partiality nor accepts a bribe." There is a difference in wording between the NASB and the NWT. NASB, Revelation 17:14, "These will rage war against the Lamb, and the Lamb will overcome them, because He is Lord of lords and King of kings, and those who are with Him are the called and chosen and faithful." NWT, "These will battle with the Lamb , but because he is Lord of lords and King of kings,  etc. What am I missing?

The Watchtower - Issue June 1st 1994 answers this:

In the Hebrew Scriptures, the expression “Lord of lords” applies only
to Jehovah. (Deuteronomy 10:17; Psalm 136:2, 3) But Peter under
inspiration said of Christ Jesus: “This One is Lord of all others [or,
“Lord of us all,” Goodspeed].” (Acts 10:36) He is indeed “Lord over
both the dead and the living.” (Romans 14:8, 9) Christians readily
acknowledge Jesus Christ as their Lord and Owner and willingly show
him obedience as his subjects, bought with his most precious blood.
And Jesus Christ has ruled as King of kings and Lord of lords over his
congregation since Pentecost 33 C.E.

To respond to the OP question, one needs to take timing into consideration. Until Jesus' exaltation in heaven after his resurrection, the Father YHWH God was the only one to whom the title "Lord of lords" was fitting.
After Jesus was "given all authority in heaven and earth" (Matthew 28:18) and after "he received a name that is above every other name" (Philippians 2:9), God the Father "crowned him with glory and honor, and appointed him over the works of His hands. All things He subjected under his feet.” By subjecting all things to him, God left nothing that is not subject to him. (Hebrews 2:7, 8)
Since then, Jesus "is at God’s right hand, for he went to heaven, and angels and authorities and powers were made subject to him." (1 Peter 3:22)
That doesn't mean though that the Father YHWH no longer is the Lord of lords, "For God 'subjected all things under [Jesus'] feet.' But when he says that ‘all things have been subjected,’ it is evident that this does not include the One who subjected all things to him." (1 Corinthians 15:27) That "One" is Jesus' God and Father YHWH (1 Corinthians 15:24)

@Mr.Bond The 1994 Watchtower quoted from the then unrevised NWT and was put in [] to indicate it not to be in the original text. The current NWT doesn’t have it here. But as my answer shows, it’s clear from the context: He (God) sent out the word to Israel through Jesus who is Lord of all. Unless you’re saying that God has a Lord, or that God sent Himself (which is nonsense imho), it means that Jesus is Lord of all except of God. I guess that’s why “others” was added in NWT 1984. Compare Hebrews 2:7,8 with 1 Corinthians 15:24-27. In Heb nothing is not subject to Jesus - 1 Cor clarifies
